# Update data on front-end with no page refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to update data from db with current data. I mean to say if db data is updated then its update on front-end with no page refresh.

Example: if a div data is 541236 && db data is 541236 and if db data is updated like this 547896 then update this data on front-end with no page refresh.

**Here is my code example.**

```
 function recordsCrawled(resp){

    var data = {'action' : 'recordsCrawled'};
    var outPut = '';

    $.post(ajaxurl, data).success(function (resp) {

       //console.log(resp);
        var json = $.parseJSON(resp); // converting response to a json obj

        //console.log(resp);

        var records_crawled = "";
        var today_crawled = "";
        var no_of_hits_today = "";
        var sites_crawled = "";

        //alert(resp)

            for(i in json){
                records_crawled = json[i].records_crawled;
                today_crawled = json[i].today_crawled;
                no_of_hits_today = json[i].no_of_hits_today;
                sites_crawled = json[i].sites_crawled;
                $('#records_crawled').html(records_crawled);
                $('#crwl_today').html(today_crawled);
                $('#no_of_hits').html(no_of_hits_today);
                $('#sits_crawled').html(sites_crawled);
            }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use technologies such as SignalR or Firebase. These technologies are really efficient for such situations. For example in SignalR you can set a Timer object on a thread to check the database for new data in a specific period of time.

```
public class MetricHub : Hub
{

}

public class BackgroundTicker : IRegisteredObject
    {

        private Timer devicesTimer;
        public BackgroundTicker()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

            hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MetricHub>();
            deviceAvailabilityTimer = new Timer(OnDeviceAvailabilityTimerElapsed, null,
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
       }
    private void OnDeviceAvailabilityTimerElapsed(object sender)
    {
        // Code to fetch data from the database
        hub.Clients.All.broadcastDeviceAvailabilityData(finalResult);
    }
 }
```

this is an example that I have worked on
Here is the javascript code on the frontend:

```
hub.client.broadcastDeviceAvailabilityData = function (devicelist) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. 
Will you please give me code example??

Answer (score 0):

Compare the div's text content with its corresponding new db value. If they are different, update the div with the new db's value:

```
if($('your_div').html != new_db_value) {
    $('your_div').html = new_db_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct answer guys. 
I just need to add this on my ajax function end.

```
.complete(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){recordsCrawled();}, 10000);
}).responseText;
```